# MS CRM 2015 web API to get GUID using telephone1

Tags: dynamics-crm, odata, dynamics-crm-2015, dynamics-crm-webapi

I am new to MS CRM 2015. I am trying to get guid using the telephone1 but I have not found any web api as we have in 2016. In MS CRM 2016 I am using the following APi to get the contact id

```
http://CRMURL/api/data/v8.0/contacts?$select=telephone1&$filter=telephone1%20eq%20%279091%27
```

It is working with 2016 but same api is not working with MS 2015. Anyone of you please help me to identify the equivalent api in 2015 to get contact id. I am using on-premises CRM.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamics CRM web api introduced in Spring release of 2015, aka update 1.

You have to use [OData endpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334767(v=crm.7).aspx) to query in your case.

```
[Your Organization Root URL]/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/ContactSet?$select=telephone1&$filter=telephone1 eq <value>
```

You can download CRM Rest builder & use within CRM.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have used this query in browser i am not getting the xml response Odata query is giving the response as the contact details.